# Can a smart contract read the gas cost of a transaction?

Tags: solidity, gas

If a transaction is sent to a smart contract, can the smart contract read the total gas cost?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [official](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html) documentation, you will find that a contract can access a set of properties of the block and its transactions, such as:

```
tx.gasprice (uint): gas price of the transaction
msg.gas (uint): remaining gas
```

Comment: tx.gasprice returns 0 on Kovan tho; im not sure what to do what that

Comment: @lopezdp I think that's because gas costs nothing on testnets.

Comment: "msg.gas" has been deprecated in favor of "gasleft()